# vhdl 32-bit addition and subtraction with overflow detection (signed number)

Tags: vhdl, addition, subtraction

Hw: I'm working on 32-bit adder and subtraction with overflow detection. It is based on 4-bit adder component which is based on a full-adder component.
when subtract is 1 --> do subtraction, else addition
Below is what I have had so far, which only have problems with sum and overflow.
I dont know why the sum is not correct (ex: 20-12=8). Please help with this!
For overflow, I tried
`overflow <= '1' when a(31)='1' and var(31)='1' and s(31)='0' else '1' when a(31)='0' and var(31)='0' and s(31)/='0' else '0';` but it doesn't work and give me the same overflow.
32-bit adder/sub:

```
use  ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity thirty_two_bit_adder is
     port (a, b: in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
        subtract: in std_logic;
        sum: out std_logic_vector (31 downto 0);
        overflow: out std_logic);
end thirty_two_bit_adder;

architecture fa_arch of thirty_two_bit_adder is
     component four_bit_adder
    port (a, b: in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
           cin : in std_logic;
           sum: out std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
           cout: out std_logic);
     end component;
signal t: std_logic_vector (6 downto 0);
signal var: std_logic_vector (31 downto 0); 
signal s: std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
begin
--LHS: 4-bit compnent ports => RHS: 32-bit entity ports
    var(31 downto 0)<= not b(31 downto 0) when subtract='1' else b(31 downto 0);
    FA0: four_bit_adder port map (a(3 downto 0) => a(3 downto 0), b(3 downto 0) => var(3 downto 0), cin => subtract, sum(3 downto 0) => s(3 downto 0), cout => t(0));
    FA1: four_bit_adder port map (a(3 downto 0) => a(7 downto 4), b(3 downto 0) => var(7 downto 4), cin => t(0), sum(3 downto 0) => s(7 downto 4), cout => t(1));
    FA2: four_bit_adder port map (a(3 downto 0) => a(11 downto 8), b(3 downto 0) => var(11 downto 8), cin => t(1), sum(3 downto 0) => s(11 downto 8), cout => t(2));
    FA3: four_bit_adder port map (a(3 downto 0) => a(15 downto 12), b(3 downto 0) => var(15 downto 12), cin => t(2), sum(3 downto 0) => s(15 downto 12), cout => t(3));
    FA4: four_bit_adder port map (a(3 downto 0) => a(19 downto 16), b(3 downto 0) => var(19 downto 16), cin => t(3), sum(3 downto 0) => s(19 downto 16), cout => t(4));
    FA5: four_bit_adder port map (a(3 downto 0) => a(23 downto 20), b(3 downto 0) => var(23 downto 20), cin => t(4), sum(3 downto 0) => s(23 downto 20), cout => t(5));
    FA6: four_bit_adder port map (a(3 downto 0) => a(27 downto 24), b(3 downto 0) => var(27 downto 24), cin => t(5), sum(3 downto 0) => s(27 downto 24), cout => t(6));
    FA7: four_bit_adder port map (a(3 downto 0) => a(31 downto 28), b(3 downto 0) => var(31 downto 28), cin => t(6), sum(3 downto 0) => s(31 downto 28), cout => overflow);
    overflow <= '1' when a(31)/=a(30) and b(31)/=b(30) else
            '0';
end fa_arch;
```

Test cases:

```
-- -3 + -6 = -9 (0xFFFFFFF7) ***correct sum, but mine is overflow***
    subtract <= '0';
    a <= "11111111111111111111111111111101";
    b <= "11111111111111111111111111111010";

-- 20 - 12 = 8 (0x00000008)  ***I got 00000021 for sum***
    subtract <= '1';
    a <= "00000000000000000000000000010100";
    b <= "00000000000000000000000000001100";

-- Large positive - large negative = overflow ***mine is not overflow***
    subtract <= '1';
    
-- large positive + large positive = overflow ***mine is not overflow***
    subtract <= '0';
    
-- large negative - large negative = no overflow ***mine is overflow***
    subtract <= '1';
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Have you got a testbench? have you tried debugging in the waveform? For this, I recommend working backwards from the output. Work out what is creating the error on the output, then work out what is creating the error for those signals, and work all the back until you find the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You've got the FA7 component driving the signal 'overflow'.  You also are driving the signal 'overflow' from inline code.   You generally can't do both, you'll get X's.

If your 4 bit adder component is correctly constructed, the FA7 output should work.